Apache/ mod_headers: environment variables (e.g. REQUEST_URI) result to (none)
while trying to inject an additional http header to mark the canonical url it is impossible to use the REQUEST_URI variable as follows:
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        <FilesMatch "\.pdf$">
            Header add Link "https://EXAMPLE.COM%{REQUEST_URI}e; rel=\"canonical\""
        </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>


In the result the rule is applied and an additional header line is created but instead of the returned header lines content
https://EXAMPLE.COM(null); rel="canonical"

I would have expected to see
https://EXAMPLE.COM/PATH/TO/MY/FILE.pfd; rel="canonical"

Any ideas why this happens and how to overcome it? Apache version is 2.4.59
Kind regards
Nazdravi

That variable is set by the rewriting module AFAIK. That is apparently not present.

I was facing the same issue as you, and finally making several tests and trying to understand how to use it with the documentation, here is the syntax that it worked for me:
<FilesMatch "\.pdf$">
      Header add Link "expr=<https\://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}>; rel=\"canonical\""
 </FilesMatch>

Hope it can help you.
Kind regards.
